# How can i append new data to sql (with python 2.7)

Tags: python, sql, csv, append

I wrote this code :

```js
df = pd.DataFrame(maindatatable)
now = datetime.date.today()
df['date'] = now
#df.rows = header
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1', index=True)

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ load data local infile 'C:/Python27/output.csv' 
into table valami
character set latin1
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines;
"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I used web-scraping a table from the internet every day, and i want to import to the sql. How can i do that, if i run my code every day, the values put into this sql table ? (append?)

output.csv code :

```js
filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
header = ['Pénznem', 'Devizanév','Egység','Pénznem_Forintban', 'date']
output.writerow(header)

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

def to_2d(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

soup=make_soup("https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok")

datatable=[]
for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        datatable.append(data.text)
maindatatable = to_2d(datatable, 4)

output.writerows(maindatatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

Comment: can you show us output.csv?

Comment: of course, i edited my question!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to solve this.Take a look at my solution with SQLAlchemy.You chould create databse and table in mysql shell,after that you can run python code(mine version is Python3 on Ubuntu).

```
import csv
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import MySQLdb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

filename='output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"w")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
header = ['Pénznem', 'Devizanév','Egység','Pénznem_Forintban', 'date']
output.writerow(header)

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok") as url:
    s = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

def to_2d(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

datatable=[]
for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        datatable.append(data.text)
maindatatable = to_2d(datatable, 4)

output.writerows(maindatatable)
resultcsv.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(maindatatable)
print (df)

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://you:"+'viktororban'+"@localhost/dbase")
df.to_sql(con=engine,name = 'newtable', if_exists='fail', index=True)
```

Of course you can change passwd!